# enum in struct: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, enums, struct

I'm not sure if I am just blind but i get this dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in following code:
header:

```
enum foo {stuff1, stuff2, stuff3};

struct bar {
    enum foo e;
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

file in which header is included:

```
void func(struct bar *b) {
    switch(b->e) {
    ...
    }
}
```

The error occures in the switch line, also code completion on b only offers me the ints x and y but not the enum.
When reading other people's problems with this error I always see them using something at a point where it was not declared yet. But this is not the case here. So why does this code not compile?

It was asked for a complete example of the problematic code. So here it goes:
h-file:

```
enum commandType {ADD_TREE, DEL_TREE, //tree
               ADD_NODE, DEL_NODE, //node
               ADD_SEGM, DEL_SEGM, //segment
               ADD_SKEL, MRG_SKEL, DEL_SKEL,  //skeleton
               ADD_BRCH, JMP_BRCH, //branchpoint
               ADD_COMM, DEL_COMM, //comment
               CHG_NODE, CHG_TREE //change active
};

struct SkelCommand {
    enum commandType type;
    int32_t id;
    int32_t prevActiveId;
};
```

c-File:

```
struct stack *undoStack = NULL;

void undo() {
//popStack returns a void*
struct skelCommand *cmd = (struct skelCommand*) popStack(undoStack);

switch(cmd->type) {
    case ADD_TREE:
        break;
    case DEL_TREE:
        break;
    case ADD_NODE:
        break;
    case DEL_NODE:
        break;
    case ADD_SEGM:
        break;
    case DEL_SEGM:
        break;
    case ADD_SKEL:
        break;
    case MRG_SKEL:
        break;
    case DEL_SKEL:
        break;
    case ADD_BRCH:
        break;
    case JMP_BRCH:
        break;
    case ADD_COMM:
        break;
    case DEL_COMM:
    break;
    case CHG_NODE:
        break;
    case CHG_TREE:
        break;
    }
}
```

in another c-file:

```
extern struct stack *undoStack;

void initialize() {
    undoStack = newStack(4069);
}
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon after `struct bar` definition.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course the semicolon does not miss in my actual code.

Comment: What compiler and can you post a complete example that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I use the MinGW gcc Compiler Version 5.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
struct skelCommand *cmd = (struct skelCommand*) popStack(undoStack);
```

but the `struct` is `SkelCommand`, uppercase `S`:

```
struct SkelCommand
{
    enum commandType type;
    int32_t id;
    int32_t prevActiveId;
};
```

Hence the error, as `struct skelCommand` is an incomplete type.

Comment: Also: the cast is not needed, void pointers can be cast to any pointer type. (removing the cast is an excellent way to trap idiots that use C++ compilers to compile C ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser, what does `popStack()` return ?

Comment: void *, according to the comments. (I don't know why) I had to add a incomplete type definition for "stack" to get it compiled. That's why you beat me on time! BTW: purely stylistic, I don't like a function call for an initialiser. I prefer an explicit assignment.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You don't need the enum keyword in your struct.</strike>

Try:

```
struct bar {
    foo e;
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

---

Edit: **The above is incorrect** and wildplasser is correct. The actual problem seems to be the fact that your **func** function takes in a **struct bar* b**. I tested with a C file in VS2010 and removing the **struct** keyword resolves your problem. Eg:

```
void func(bar *b) {
    switch(b->e) {
    ...
    }
}
```

More edits:

Turns out what MS thinks is C and what is actual C is not the same (at least in VS2010). See comments below for the correct answer.

Comment: Yest you do need the enum keyword in C. (are you using a C++ compiler, by any chance?) You also need a semicolon after the '}'

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for pointing that out for me. I should've actually run the code before putting in my 2 cents.

Comment: Your edit is wrong as well. C requires the `struct` keyword there.

Comment: I guess the VC2010 compiler does not comply with C89 completely. This compiles. Although I had to declare the struct using "typedef struct {...} bar;"

Comment: The original fragment (with the semicolon after the struct, and a few case added inide the struct) compiles fine. (and does nothing). ALSO: Microsoft is not known for its standards-compliance.

Comment: @Wes: If you use a typedef it will work without the `struct` keyword. But that has nothing to do with the OP's issue (which isn't exhibited by the code above).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys. I probably learnt more than the OP did today :)